# How to use route parameters with Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm having difficulty connecting the dots with the `router.params` objects with express.

Right now I'd like to have the `button-success` button in the code below point to a url that reads `someaddress.com/formula/:item._id`

**HTML: (EJS Templating Engine)**

```
  <% formulas.forEach(function(item){ %>
  <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-1-2 pure-u-md-1-4 pure-u-xl-1-5">
      <div class="formula-block centered" id="<%= item._id %>">
        <h4 class="padded-top"> <%= item.name %></h4>
        <p> <%= item.description %></p>
          <button class="button-success pure-button"><a href="/formula/<%= item._id %>">Show</a></button>
          <button class="button-warning pure-button">Delete</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% }); %>
```

I am pairing that with this Express route:

```
router.get('/formula/:id', function(req, res){
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('formulas');
  var id = req.params.id;
  collection.find({"_id": id}, {}, function(e, doc){
  res.render('formula/:id', {
    formula: doc,
    title: `formula for ${doc.name}`,
    description: `modify and view ${doc.name} formula`
      });
    });
});
```

which then uses the information from the MongoDB document to generate the page.

It's not clear to me how you do this from looking at the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your code is not exactly right. In your html you use `formulas` (plural) but in the router you pass an object to `res.render` with a prop `formula` (singular). If i understand your code they should be the same (`formulas`). Next thing is the first parameter to res.router should be the name of your html file without extention so if the name is formulas.html or formulas.ejs then you need to use `res.render('formulas',...`. Once the view is rendered the button should point to `/formula/the-id-of-the-formula`

Comment: @Molda - I omitted code because someone cast a vote to have my question closed due to lack of clarity.  The <code>formulas</code> bit in the html comes from a variable that was passed into it from another route.  The <code>formula</code> variable is being set as a variable in the JSON object, so in this case it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Ok i just read what you originally wrote. So the url you seem to be confused about is `/formula/:id`. What you need to know is that the `:id` is only a placeholder not an actual value. So if there's a request for `/formula/1234` then the `router.get('/formula/:id',...` will handle it, express will parse the id and make it available as `req.params.id`.

Comment: @Molda - thank you.  Okay, so if I want to display the `formula`  template, but with the `/formula/:id` url, do I just do `res.render('formula', {JSON data})`?

Comment: Yes. I assume that by `JSON data` you mean javascript object, right? I noticed many people refer to it as JSON but it's just an object. JSON is a data format used to transfer data. object -> {a:1}, json -> '{"a":1}' <- it's basicly a string with a specific format. :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  If you want to put this as an answer I'll upvote and mark as correct.